# pass a groovy array to javascript code

Tags: grails

I try to pass an array  from a controller to a javascript code into a gsp page.  I tried with
Controller    :

```
           def stat(){
           def listSubject = [["Physique", 10, 85, 1], ["Arabe", 20, 14, 3]] 

            [listSubject]
                             }
```

stat.gsp :

```
               var data=${listSubject} ;
```

But it looks like considering the data    as if it was a string and not an array. 
I tried also to add

```
             var data=${listSubject.encodeAsJavaScript()} ;
```

But No result is matched. Please i need your helps :( Thanks

Comment: Look at the *actual* HTML of the resulting page. That will say a good bit about the problem, and such output should be included in the question.

Comment: `[listSubject]` has no meaning outside of the context of the controller action. It will have a meaning if the model (of MVC) is tailored appropriately, which means `[listSubject: listSubject]` will create a key<>value in the model which can then be accessed in the gsp as `${listSubject}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to pass data in gsp to javascript is JSON. Try this:

```
def stat(){
    def listSubject = [["Physique", 10, 85, 1], ["Arabe", 20, 14, 3]] as grails.converters.JSON
    [listSubject:listSubject]
}
```