# passing map from grails to javascript

Tags: javascript, json, grails, dictionary

My problem is passing Map object from grails controller to JavaScript. 
I have the following code inside controller

```
def scoreValue=new HashMap<String,String>();
scoreValue.put("0","poor");
scoreValue.put("1","good");
...

return (view:'viewname',model:[scoreValue:scoreValue]);
```

I have been searching for solution and have got this link [pass a groovy array to javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25415050/pass-a-groovy-array-to-javascript-code). but could not help.

What I did was change the return statement to

`return (view:'viewname',model:[scoreValue:scoreValue as grails.converters.JSON])`
and inside gsp view I have the following code.

```
<g:if test="${scoreValue}">
     var scoreValue=${scoreValue};
</g:if>
```

But what i got inside html page is the following

```
 var scoreValue={&quot;0&quot;:&quot;Failure&quot;,&quot;1&quot;:&quot;Poor&quot;}
```

any help would be appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var scoreValue= <g:applyCodec encodeAs="none">${scoreValue}</g:applyCodec>;
```

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a few ways of handling GSP encoding. In addition to D. Kossatz's answer, these methods will help you out (see more at [mrhaki's excellent Grails Goodness blog](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2013/11/grails-goodness-generating-raw-output.html))

```
 var scoreValue=${raw(scoreValue)};

 var scoreValue=${scoreValue.encodeAsRaw()}
```

Please be aware that there is an inherent risk of cross-site scripting vulnerabilities when rendering user input unprotected on the page. So long as you know for *certain* that only you can set that value, and proper safe-checks to ensure it is what it is supposed to be, you should be fine.

Comment: when i did as you said i got  `var scoreValue= {0=poor, 1=good} `. and showing error because it is considering good and poor as variables not strings.